# RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service?

Tags: android, android-camera

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>                                                                              at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
>                                                                              at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:423)
>                                                                              at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:384)
>                                                                              at ge.baqari.dev.capture.ui.view.CameraView.surfaceChanged(CameraView.kt:39)
>                                                                              at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:617)
>                                                                              at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
>                                                                              at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:692)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I found many answers but non of them helped me, I am trying to create custom camera view, implementing surface holder, but it crashes always with Camera.open() method, with parameter and without parameter same, crashes

```
class CameraView : android.view.SurfaceView, android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    var camera: android.hardware.Camera? = null
    var previewing = false
    var cameraCallback: CameraCallBack? = null
    var pictureCallback: PictureCallback? = null
    var cameraParameters: android.hardware.Camera.Parameters? = null

    private fun init() {
        holder.addCallback(this)
        holder.setType(SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL)
    }

    constructor(context: android.content.Context, attrs: android.util.AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    override fun surfaceCreated(surfaceHolder: android.view.SurfaceHolder) {

    }

    override fun surfaceChanged(surfaceHolder: android.view.SurfaceHolder, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
        if (context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
            if (previewing) {
                camera?.stopPreview()
                previewing = false
            }

            if (camera == null) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                    cameraParameters!!.setPreviewSize(i1, i2)
                    camera!!.parameters = cameraParameters!!
                    camera!!.startPreview()
                    camera!!.setPreviewDisplay(holder)
                    previewing = true
                } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun surfaceDestroyed(surfaceHolder: android.view.SurfaceHolder) {
        camera!!.stopPreview()
        camera!!.release()
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try rebooting the device. Sometimes, the camera service gets opened and never closed, and the only consistent way to recover from that I have found is to reboot the device.

Comment: I have rebooted 2 times, but deal, tried with two android device but both are huawei device

Comment: After release, set camera var to null.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in CameraParameters, parameters are null and you try to set null parameters

Fix:

```
camera = Camera.open(android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
cameraParameters = camera!!.parameters
cameraParameters!!.setPreviewSize(i1, i2)
camera!!.parameters = cameraParameters!!
camera!!.startPreview()
camera!!.setPreviewDisplay(holder)
```

Also you can use this library for [camera preview](https://github.com/google/cameraview)

Comment: @BaqarGogia Do you set permission for camera?

Comment: not permission i set uses-feature for hardware.camera

Comment: I mean do you add camera permission in Manifest ? You can read about permissions here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/index.html

Comment: i havenot added, because i am not using built-in camera app for startactivityresult i use camera feature, thanks for suggestion ))), but either it not helpful

Comment: @BagarGoggia Even if you use Camera feature you need permission))

Comment: Look at official tutorial https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: I wrote it from official tutorial

Comment: why you don't want try to add permission?)